# SQL query from SageMaker with Amazon Athena

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, amazon-sagemaker

I am trying to query my s3 files (JSON format) from SageMaker with Athena. The s3 location looks like this: s3://name/year=2017/month=01/day=01. Here are stored some  JSON files which I want to query with Athena. I created a connection variable, next in the variable connection.execute("query") I run the query to create the table.

query:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE testing (
id int

)    PARTITIONED BY (day string) ROW FORMAT  serde 'org.apache.hive.hcatalog.data.JsonSerDe' with serdeproperties ( 'paths'='id' ) LOCATION 's3://name/2018/07/';""")
```

Next I run the sql query:

```
df = pd.read_sql("SELECT * FROM default.testing WHERE day='01' LIMIT 10 ", conn)
```

After that I print the DataFrame but I get a 0 value instead.

The JSON looks like this:

```
{"shoe_number":43,"country_id":6.. etc
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You need to execute `MSCK REPAIR TABLE <table name>` query after creating the table to auto discover partitions under table location specified. `SELECT` queries after that should provide results as expected.

~Bhargava